# Applying Tolerance for vpasolve

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to apply a tolerance to vpasolve? I am attempting to solve an equation that has been accepted to represent the solution to a nomogram. It is not necessary to have an exact solution, as it takes a lot of time. If there is some way to apply a tolerance to vpasolve, or an alternative method to solving the equation it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to help you with vpasolve, but you can try fsolve or fzero function. It is possible to pass tolerance preferences via optimoptions function there.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fzero.html
http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimoptions.html

Cheers.